# I am very new to kivy and i was following this youtuber called Tech with Tim, the following happened after his Kivy Tutorial #4

Tags: python, kivy

so i have the very basic python code and i wanted to create a kv file for it. i am on visual studio btw, just a reference. i have tried changing the #kivy tag. it didnt work
i dont know how to fix it, its daunting, please help.
My code is as follows

the kv file is like this:

#:kivy 2.0.0
:
GridLayout:
cols: 1

```
    Gridlayout:
        cols: 2

        Label:
            text: "Name: "
        
        TextInput:
            multiline: False

        Label:
            text: "Email: "    
        TextInput:
            multiline: False
    Button:
        text: "Submit"
```

i am getting this error :

```
 raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name), kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <Gridlayout>
```

````
kivy.require('2.0.0')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class CoolGrid(Widget):
    the details here

class CoolApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CoolGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    CoolApp().run()```
````

Comment: Maybe the error is in the first line in your kv file. Change Gridlayout for GridLayout (capital L).

Comment: yeah that fixed it, but the output screen isnt what i expected, the submit button is huge and i dont see my labels

Comment: Try to change the parent class from the CoolGrid: CoolGrid(BoxLayout) instead of class CoolGrid(Widget)

Comment: i found out the problem, it wasnt that. i essentially had 2 codes that were overlapping and i didnt realise it. so the older code's button was so big it covered the kv code. i fixed it by removing the chunk under my CoolGrid class and just writing that in the kv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in the first line in your kv file. Change Gridlayout for GridLayout (capital L)

All classes name in kivy are like this, the first letter of any word are capital letters: GridlLayout, BoxLayout, TextInput